# Get a float to move past multiple previous floats

Tags: html, css

Lets say I want a mobile-first layout where there is a vertical column of li elements.
When you click any of the li elements on a mobile device, a new li is created just below it "drawer" style, and expands to show the content pertaining to the clicked li element.

Simply:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li class='data'>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Lets say you blow that exact same layout out to desktop mode (like 1200px wide). Now, the layout should still be stacked li tags, but when you click one, the same thing should happen in the dom (new li below the clicked one), but the data should display to the right in a 2-column fashion, with the new li taking up the space to the right of the ul column. The top of the li, no matter which one you clicked on, should be even with the top of the ul element.

Sure, this is possible, they say. But! There's a catch:

I don't want to use absolute positioning on the data on the right side, because it makes content below it move up behind it when it's longer than the ul.

When a li further down in the list is floated right, it won't mover further up than the previous one, despite what I though I knew about floats.

Again, I'm looking for a CSS only solution. I already fixed this with absolute positioning/height, but I'd like the height to be dynamic.

Here is a jsfiddle set up for you to check out with the almost-working-but-still-broken layout:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mz5RM/6/

Here you see the text clearing the bottom of the container as expected, and it would respect a dynamic height on li 3.

But... I want it allllll the way at the top, flush with li 1.

Does anyone have a solution for this? This is an interesting problem that would be pretty sweet to get solved.

Here is what it SHOULD look like, but this one uses the absolute positioning/fixed height fix, which allows trailing content to move up behind it, as you can see. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Mz5RM/5/

The problem is that my content is dynamic. So this solution is much less than ideal. I'm starting to see that my no-js solution is just about impossible...

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - It's almost like you're saying you want to build a house, but you don't want to use wood to build a framework... Sometimes you have to look back and see if what you have done with your code is worthwhile holding in order to create the output that you desire. *edit* - that said - I hope someone does come up with a solution for this, I'm quite curious to see what it would be.

Comment: I don't think it's unrealistic to strive for a mobile first, progressively enhancing framework that doesn't require JS... and since I've spent several hours trying to figure it out on my own and doing research on it, SO is my last resource. The mentality that users should "just upgrade" is, in my opinion, lacking something...

Comment: That said, the fallback of having a fixed height isn't the end of the world. It's just not my ideal :D

Comment: I'm not against the "mobile" first aspect - it was more like, you don't want to use absolute positioning, no javascript, and do you want to layout your divs in a different format in order to attain this. You already put restrictions to viable solutions to get the result you wanted.

Comment: I achieve css-only solutions all the time without absolute positioning. This is me trying to continue to find something equally satisfying. Its fine if you don't have a solution, but just saying that will do. Telling me I'm asking too much defeats the point of my entire post.